# spring boot read property value from file content (not property file)

Tags: spring-boot, properties

Is there a way to inject the value of a property from file content?

In my case i want to read a public certificate:

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "certificate")
@Value
public class Certificate {
    String publicKey;


}
```

The certificate is in a file with content like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC3DCCAcSgAwIBAgIGAYYWvEf6MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMC8xLTArBgNVBAMM
JDhjOGVmNjQxLTEwMGEtNDUxMi1iOTFhLWM3Mzc5NDcwMTdjMzAeFw0yMzAyMDMx
...
4/eJiZvtUhlPTZAeBCbmwHhLFufMRrYtOje/JLDcXFUhF4Ypb6BITbbWijJ7oMqP
1Amyt3eKiVhFdIVk1U4gp19wda4oeKP+5gaPTvAlYrN+EWdC1lUDRBipcM5zioFk
CwELjzRA2Dzg059g93NN7Q==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Currently i have 2 ways to load this as property:

- load it in env variable with shell `CERTIFICATE_PUBLIC_KEY="$(cat ./certs/device-cert.pem)"` - need to run before
- change the file to a property file beginning with `certificate.publicKey=`
  and adding "\n" at every line end and adding it as additional property source

Is there a way to load the file content directly into a property on start?
At the moment i don't want to loose the Spring Boot Property feature - because it is really flexible.
If not possible i can of course just load the file and use its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with Spring. You can add the following option to your application properties file:

```
spring:
  config:
    import: configtree:/specify_the_path_where_your_file_is_located/
```

Then you should put your public key file to that location and give a name to this file according to your desired configuration properties:

> certificate.publicKey

And you're done here! During application startup the content of that file will be injected to that property and will be both accesible from your configuration properties or from `Environment` bean

Comment: thanks!  2 days ago i read about how load secrets from files/ mounts in kubernetes, with configtree - i did not made the connection :-P